# Send your current location from one activity to another

Tags: android, google-maps

i would like to obtain my lčocation in one activity, then send it to another (when i click button) and there show my location on maps. 
Here's my code (the problem is,map doesn't animate to my current location, I believe first activity doesn't obtain current location and sends null to second activity):

```
public class ActivityMain extends MapActivity {



private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;
private GeoPoint currentGeoPoint = null;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);

    try{
         locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
         locationListener = new getLocation();
         locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);


    }
    catch (NullPointerException e){
        System.out.println("Null");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

public void onButton1Click(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityMain.this, ActivityMap.class);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

     if(currentGeoPoint != null){
         intent.putExtra("lat", currentGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6());
         intent.putExtra("long", currentGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6());
     }
     else{

         try{
             locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
             locationListener = new getLocation();
             locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);


        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("Null");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
     }

     Context c = getApplicationContext();
     c.startActivity(intent);

     //Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityMain.this, ActivityMap.class);
    //this.startActivity(intent);

}


public void onButton2Clik (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityMain.this, ActivityListCategories.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);

    } 

class getLocation implements LocationListener {


    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null){
        GeoPoint currentPoint = getCurrentPoint(location);
        currentGeoPoint = currentPoint; 

        }

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getProvider() + " enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getProvider() + " disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
    }


}



public GeoPoint getLastKnownPoint (){

    GeoPoint lastKnownPoint = null;
    Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(getProvider());
    if(lastKnownLocation != null){
         lastKnownPoint = getCurrentPoint(lastKnownLocation);
    }

    return lastKnownPoint;
}


public GeoPoint getCurrentPoint (Location location){
    GeoPoint currentPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude()*1E6),(int)(location.getLongitude()*1E6));
    return currentPoint;

}

public String getProvider() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    String Provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    return Provider;
}



@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    LocationManager newLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager = newLocationManager;
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);


}

protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);


}

protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);


}
```

}

and here is code for second activity

```
public class ActivityMap extends MapActivity {

private MapController mapController;
private MapView mapView;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;
private GeoPoint currentGeoPoint;
private Location currentLocation = null;
private ClassMapOverlay currPos;
private ClassCustomItemizedOverlay<ClassCustomOverlayItem> mallsOverlay;
private List<ClassMall> malls;



// TODO: AsyncTAsk

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitymap);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(bundle != null){
            currentGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(bundle.getDouble("lat") / 1E6),(int)(bundle.getDouble("long")/1E6));
            animateToCurrentPoint(currentGeoPoint);

        }

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapController = mapView.getController();


    public GeoPoint getLastKnownPoint (){

        GeoPoint lastKnownPoint = null;
        Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(getProvider());
        if(lastKnownLocation != null){
             lastKnownPoint = getCurrentPoint(lastKnownLocation);
        }

        return lastKnownPoint;
    }


    public GeoPoint getCurrentPoint (Location location){
        GeoPoint currentPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude()*1E6),(int)(location.getLongitude()*1E6));
        return currentPoint;

    }

    public void animateToCurrentPoint(GeoPoint currentPoint){

        mapController.animateTo(currentPoint);
        mapController.setCenter(currentPoint);
        mapController.setZoom(15);
    }


    public void drawCurrPositionOverlay(){
        List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        overlays.remove(currPos);
        Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.me);
        currPos = new ClassMapOverlay(marker,mapView);
        GeoPoint drawMyPoint = null;

        if(currentGeoPoint==null){
            drawMyPoint = getLastKnownPoint();
        }

       else {

           drawMyPoint = currentGeoPoint;
       }

        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(drawMyPoint, "Moja adresa:", getAddress(currentLocation));
        currPos.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        overlays.add(currPos);
        currPos.setCurrentLocation(currentLocation);




    }



    public void drawMallsOverlay(List <ClassMall> malls){

        List <Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        overlays.remove(mallsOverlay);
        Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.malls);
        mallsOverlay = new ClassCustomItemizedOverlay<ClassCustomOverlayItem>(marker, mapView);

        if(malls.size() > 0){
            for(ClassMall temp: malls ){
                GeoPoint mallPoint = getLatLon(temp.getAddress());
                ClassCustomOverlayItem overlayItem = new ClassCustomOverlayItem(mallPoint,temp.getName(),temp.getAddress(), temp.getUrl());
                mallsOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), temp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


        overlays.add(mallsOverlay);

    }


    public String getProvider() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        String Provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        return Provider;
    }


    public  String getAddress (Location location){

        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());  
        String sAddress = "";

        try{
            List <Address> address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
            if(address.size() > 0){
                for(int i = 0; i < address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
                    sAddress += address.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                }
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return sAddress;

    } 

    public GeoPoint getLatLon (String address){
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        GeoPoint point = null;
        List <Address> addresses = null;
        try {
                addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
                if(addresses.size() > 0){
                     point = new GeoPoint((int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                                                  (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude()*1E6));
                    }


        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return point;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

}

And please can you tell me how can i asynchronously obtain my current location ?

Comment: Are you sure youre not getting the location? Probably its able to retrieve it but for some reasons not able to send it to the next activity. Try adding log statements just after you get the location to make sure youre receiving the coordinates from location manager.

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Comment: I can't remember any more, sorry  :/ (have I solved it, or if I have, how)

Answer (score 1):

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

intent = new Intent(LegalSeeFoods.this, MapDemoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("lat", location .latitude);
intent.putExtra("long", location .longitude);
startActivity(intent);
```

IN **MapDemoActivity.class**

`mapView.getController().setCenter(point);` **<---** TO animate to location

Comment: I've tried your solution but I got  null pointer exception:  ava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.projekt.app/com.projekt.app.ActivityMap}: java.lang.NullPointerException ... ActivityMap

Comment: @MAC Please see my related question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851013/send-data-from-one-activity-to-another-regularly