# How do i get lat/long dynamically in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to get two lat/long points dynamically when i plot two markers(source & destination) on Google maps. Where i can use those lat/long points for my further implementation.

Please help me how do i get it.

Comment: http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/map-api-in-android.html
and.... http://stackoverflow.com/a/10597160/1289716

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. Might help you..:)

```
mapView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            GeoPoint p = null;

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(),
                        (int) event.getY());
                mapBackButton.setText(p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + ","
                        + p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6 + "Action is : "
                        + event.getAction());
                return true;
                Toast.makeText(
                        getBaseContext(),
                        p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," + p.getLongitudeE6()
                                / 1E6 + "Action is : " + event.getAction(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

     mapView.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
```

Edit it according to your need.

Comment: Tariq, thanks for responding, in your code if statement it getting false and therefore couldn't get actual result.

Comment: Modified little bit and i put ACTION_DOWN instead of ACTION_UP, it worked fine. But when i drag map to other location the touch listener if getting failed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) to get an instance of [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) (using  [getLastKnownLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29) method) which contains has got [getLatitude](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) and [getLongitude](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getLongitude%28%29) methods, then use these method to get latitude and longitude.